# Adding a custom play button for Youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, youtube

I use a popup for Youtube videos. Accordingly, I use the "yotubevid" class.
My HTML code looks like this:

```
<a class="youtubevideo" href="https://youtu.be/">
<img class="youtubevideo-poster" src="example.com/image.png" width="100%" height="auto"></a>
```

This class and div trigger a popup in the background. And it works well. How can I add a custom play button without breaking this class structure?

Comment: what do you mean by custom play button? do you want to prevent the autoplay ?

Comment: A dedicated play button for embedded youtube video. For example like this: https://codepen.io/rooc/pen/bONbqw

But existing solutions do not conform to the class structure and disable the pop-up window. As a result I want to add a play button without breaking the class of the html code above.

Comment: Need you code sample to debug and look for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you exacty needed...!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .playBtn{
        width: 2em;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        vertical-align: middle;
        z-index:1;
    }
    a{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<body>
        <a class="youtubevideo" href="https://www.youtube.com/">
            <img class="playBtn" src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/b/255-2554901_recording-icon-png.png" alt="">
            <img class="youtubevideo-poster" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="100vw" height="auto">
        </a>
        
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works, but there seems to be a minor problem .The page is breaking.This usually happens on my page when html tags are not closed correctly. Is there a problem with the html tag of the play button?

Comment: I found what caused the problem. Style css for .a is not suitable for my site. I just deleted the style file for ".a". And now it works fine. Thanks for your code.